# Composer update: You have local changes to '.php_cs'; cannot switch branches

Tags: php, intellij-idea, composer-php

Strange error, never seen this before.

I am doing a: composer update and am seeing this error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                              
Failed to execute git checkout '43c276df6e94e498bf530538aea53876a24fc47c' -- && git reset --hard
'43c276df6e94e498bf530538aea53876a24fc47c' --                                                                                                                                                      
error: You have local changes to '.php_cs'; cannot switch branches.
```

I have tried:

1. php composer.phar install --prefer-dist
2. Deleting vendor folders

I am using Intellij as my IDEA and the one thing that I did do recently which "could" have casued this problem was to remove files from the IDEA that had been marked as TEXT FILES when in fact they were PHP files.

Comment: It seems to be related to git, isn't it ?

Comment: I am not sure... could not work it out so nuked the directory and fetched the code again. This seemed to sort it out.